# Force object type based on an interface

Tags: typescript, zod

I want to force a Zod type based on a TypeScript interface:

```
import { z } from 'zod';

interface Foo {
  id: string;
  count: number;
}

                  //
const t = z.object<Foo>({
  count: z.number(),
  id: z.string()
})
```

How can I do it? The code above doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "force"?

Comment: I mean that it will force the z.object param to be the same type of Foo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give `t` the respective `z.ZodType` type.

```
const t: z.ZodType<Foo> = z.object({
  count: z.number(),
})
// Error: Property 'id' is missing in type '{ count: number; }' but required in type 'Foo'
```

Alternatively, you can use a helper function:

```
const schemaForType = <T>() => <S extends z.ZodType<T, any, any>>(arg: S) => {
  return arg;
};

schemaForType<Foo>()(
  z.object({
    id: z.string(),
    count: z.number(),
  })
);

schemaForType<Foo>()(
  z.object({
    id: z.string(),
  })
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Error:  Property 'count' is missing in type '{ id: string; }' but required in type 'Foo'.(2345)
);
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.8.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLzgXzgMyhEcBEyEAJvgNwBQFwAdjAKZSYCGAxvXAGIQSIVxxgxAFxwAzjCi0A5pQGsIAVzqiaikACNGlNFQU0J41gAt6IZtygAVAJ5gOAXjgAeKwD4AFAEo4Dty4BlOHoADwYaYjEUADoALRJbe1cAGjhmGhtU9Js3T2YoaVEAnz8+ASh6GEUoGjSCnUoKMRMzC2hE+mduCE8vD34YiA0AK3pWGA8EAYEhUWRoiSkaaW9k6bgFZRg56LVNRlWBtC8KL0bm03NLDq6eXv6BeaHR8cn12ZjFmUOBY4oAen+cAAeqCweCIXAAKJQHBQURwAAKOHssBscAA5Js6BjBFEQMAxGIZIJajA7BwMUgPl9lmR0LiNIp4BUAI6KYAVYikuDk+yY7oY6IeABMAGYACwAVhOZwoQA)

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to not create a variable only for that?

Comment: you could also use a helper-function. See my edit

Comment: That's great. Any reason I don't get autocomplete from typescript when trying to see the missing properties?

Comment: Seems like there are too many layers of indirection which makes the autocompletion not realize what properties are supposed to be in the object. But hard to properly judge this without looking into the compiler :/